# Why am I not able to display a mp4 video on chrome?

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, video, browser

I'm building a website on wordpress, I tried to upload a mp4 video file through my dashboard but I wasn't able to do so. So I simply uploaded through my filezilla. Then I style a little bit and after I worked on the autoplay and stuff like that, I tried on my chrome browser, when I found out that it doesn't work. The weird thing is that this very video is possible to be displayed from all the other browser: firefox, safari and opera. The weirder thing is that on http://caniuse.com/ I discovered that indeed this extention should be supported by chrome.
Here's my code:

```
 <div class="video-container">
                <video autoplay loop id="bgvid">
                    <source src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/ChickapeaRecipesPageHeader3.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
                </video>
            </div>
```

and here it is the css:

```
video#bgvid { 
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.video-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

and bootstrap as a framework.

Any clue why it is not displayed on chrome?

UPDATE:

Here is the link of the webpage where the video is: http://chickapea.larchedigitalmedia.com/recipes/

ANOTHER UPDATE:

There are two main problems: I added another format and an image in order to create a fallback, in case the browser doesn't support mp4 (I downloaded an app for mac called free mp4 converter to solve the problem of the fact that my video was a m4v even if it had a mp4 extension, even in that case it didn't work) so now it is visible on google chrome, but it is not visible on my phone (android - nexus 5x). So I don't really have a clue about what it is going on (my phone is not able to display the video and when I scroll down there's a weird effect with the element that I put on the video, a div with an h2 inside).

My code now is:

```
<div class="out">
                    <div id="in">
                        <h2>Chickapea Blog</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="video-container">
                <video autoplay loop id="bgvid">
                    <source src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/ChickapeaRecipesPageHeader.webm" type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"'/>
                    <source src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/ChickapeaRecipesPageHeader.mp4" type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/background-faq.jpg" title="Your browser does not support the <video> tag">
                </video>
            </div>
```

And the css is:

```
.recipes .out {
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    width: 60%;
    height: 29%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    top: 50%;
    border: 3px solid white;
}
.recipes #in {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    height: 70%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 15%;
    background-color: rgba(141,198,63,0.6);
    padding: 4%;
}
.recipes #in h2 {
    font-family: 'Knewave', cursive;
    color: white;
}
```

for the video:

```
video#bgvid { 
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.video-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

Comment: what is the full file path to the video?

Comment: http://chickapea.larchedigitalmedia.com/recipes/

Comment: @MarcoMaffei I can see the video in chrome.

Comment: With Chrome 50.0.2661.102 on OSX 10.11.5 I can't see the video. Chrome can be a bit tricky with mp4 sometimes but it is meant to be supported. One thing to note - inspecting the video file with ffprobe suggests it is actually m4v format rather than mp4.

Comment: Works for me on Windows / Chrome. Like @Mick suggested it might be worth converting from M4V container to MP4 just incase some software is being too strict about format. Also consider clearing Chrome browser cache if all fails (could be just showing you the old not working page on every load / refresh)

Comment: I don't know why, I'm not able to see it with chrome, even on my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For CSS**

```
.bgvideo{
        position:fixed;
        right:0;
        bottom:0;
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        width:auto;
        height:auto;
        z-index: -989; 
        -webkit-filter: brightness(.5);
        filter: brightness(.5);

}
```

**in HTML**

```
<video autoplay loop muted class="bgvideo">
    <source src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/ChickapeaRecipesPageHeader.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

i did without codecs. run this code if it works then customize. this is Full Background video.

Answer (score 2):

The video is in fact visible on mobile but due to a built-in mobile browser filter, you cannot autoplay a video because it may consumes bandwidth on cellular data.  The only way to play a video on mobiles is with user interaction, meaning that the user must click the play button if they want to watch it and of course consume their cellular data if they are not on WiFi. That said, I was able to see the video player on my iPhone when I visited your website but I am unable to click play due to your z-index value. You should either increase the z-index stack order for the video-container on mobiles so that users can click the play button, or replace the video-container with an image or slider on mobiles which is what most website do including Airbnb.com, paypal.com, etc. You can do that with @media class.